# Connecting to EC2 instance from Android phone

Tags: java, android, ruby, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use EC2 to run a ruby server for an Android app. I have a physical Android phone running a Java app trying to connect to a ruby script running on my EC2 instance. I set it up with an Elastic IP which I am using in my Android app like so:

```
requestSocket = new Socket("53.244.196.69", 2000); // IP changed just in case
```

On the EC2 instance I am running the simple ruby script shown here:

```
server = TCPServer.open(2000)

loop {
client = server.accept
client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
client.close
}
```

As soon as I call the line of Java code above, it throws an exception saying that the connection was refused.

I have the windows firewall disabled on my EC2 instance and I have the ports open in my security group so I am not sure what else could be the problem?

Any help is very much appreciated as I am very new to cloud development. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out! I needed to change my ruby call like so: "server = TCPServer.open("0.0.0.0", 2000)"